# Join query using eloquent model mapping

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to do this

```
select notifications.id, reservations.number from 
notifications 
JOIN reservations 
ON notifications.reservation_id = reservations.id 
WHERE notifications.status = 1
```

using eloquent so I have this this

```
$await = Notification::with('Reservation')->
select('notifications.id', 'reservations.number')
->where('notifications.status', '=', 1)->get();

return Response::json($awaitLists);
```

In my Notification model

```
public function Reservation() {
        return $this->belongsTO('Reservation');
    }
```

In my Reservation Model

```
public function notification() {
        return $this->hasMany('Notification');
    }
```

So notification belongs to reservation while reservation has a 1 to many relationship

My question is why can't what I have tried works. I keep getting Unknown column 'reservation.number' but i do have column called number in the reservations table.  I know they is a way to use eloquent relationship mapper to do this.

Comment: `with` doesn't join tables. It runs separate queries. You need to `join` the tables manually, or rely on `relationship`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```php
$notifications = Notification::where('status','=',1)->get();

foreach($notifications as $notification) {
    $id = $notification->id;
    $num = $notification->reservation->number;

    $await = [$id,$num];
    var_dump($await);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to eager load the reservation relationship, otherwise you run into the n+1 issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is because eager loading relationships doesn't actually perform a join. It uses two separate queries, and then the relationship fields are assigned after the queries are run.

So, when you do `Notification::with('Reservation')->get()`, it is running two SQL statements, approximately:

```
Notification::with('Reservation')->get();
// select * from notifications;
// select * from reservations where id in (?, ?, ...);
```

You can see the actual queries run with a `dd(DB::getQueryLog())`, if you're interested.

How you move forward depends on what you need to do. If you need to duplicate your existing query exactly, then you'll need to manually perform the joins.

```
$notifications = Notification::select('notifications.id', 'reservations.number')
    ->join('reservations', 'notifications.reservation_id', '=', 'reservations.id`)
    ->where('notifications.status', '=', 1)
    ->get();

foreach($notifications as $notification) {
    print_r($notification->number);
}
```

Otherwise, you can just use the objects as they are built by Laravel:

```
$notifications = Notification::with('Reservation')->where('status', '=', 1)->get();

foreach($notifications as $notification) {
    print_r($notification->Reservation->number);
}
```